# why postmant request and scrapy request send me to diferent web?

Tags: python-3.x, post, scrapy, request

i did this spider, and when i make a request with that, send me to diferent web
a regret that I put the same parameters and almost the same header

```
def start_requests(self):

        url ="https://assr.parcelquest.com/Statewide"
        rows =self.getPin('parcels/Parcel.csv')

        for row in rows:
            params = {
                'co3': 'MRN',
                'apn': 022-631-01, 
                'recaptchaSuccess':'0',
                'IndexViewModel': 'PQGov.Models.IndexViewModel'
            }
            header = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept' : '*/*',
                'host':'assr.parcelquest.com',
                'Referer': 'https://assr.parcelquest.com/Statewide/Index',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36',
                'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Connection':'keep-alive'

                
            }


            #print(params)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url,headers=header,body=json.dumps(params),method='POST',callback=self.property,meta = {'parcel':row},dont_filter=True)
```

this is postman:

[image]

could explain me anybody why?

Comment: I bet `'apn': 022-631-01,` does something different to what you expect :) In my version of Python it’s a syntax error (`SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers`)

Comment: maybe because i read a file instead to write only 022-631-01, but this a should be  '022-631-01', sorry for my mistake